# Quick access to a table from IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

If you type a database table name in the "Search Everywhere" dialogue it will appear in the bottom of the list and I have to scroll to open the table. What is the trick to access a table quicker?

Comment: Navigate | Symbol will significantly speed up the process, but it doesn't search for tables names only, so not sure if it covers your request completely.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov thanks, yet it reduces unrelated result but yet have to select by scrolling down the list.

Comment: How about the [database tool window](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Databases+and+SQL+Editor+in+PhpStorm)? I can not test it atm, but if this view is open, you should be able to open the desired table quickly.

Comment: @DavidArtmann Looking for keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are searching for `alt+f7` alias for `find usages`.

To quote:

> Find the usages of (references to) the selected item (data source, table or column) in your source files and libraries.

[More at the jetbrains help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/database-tool-window.html#find_usages).

**First edit** I have asked the requester to add information if the answer is not what he was searching.  The question was not updated but I'll post some links.

- Keyboard mapping on `jetbrains` products is no magic, you can find
  complete shortcut list for *phpstorm* here:
  [By Keystroke](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/keyboard-shortcuts-by-keystroke.html) or [By category](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/keyboard-shortcuts-by-category.html)

If you can not find it here it is likely such shortcut does not exist.

- If you want to create a custom shortcut you have to change your
  *keyboard map*:

  [Configuring Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Comment: I'm not. Can you remove this answer

Comment: The answer is vatid to your question. Please improve your question with additional informaion and/or screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not a valid answer. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  Since you did not improve your question, I'm posting general links for all shortcuts in *phpstorm* and the way to configure your own shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You can search it via Ctrl+shift+n search tool. It will be shown in symbols and database tabs
[image]

Then when you open table structure from search results you can go to filter row view through this icon:
[image]

Thanks, hope it helps.